# Fail to write file with permission 0777

Tags: go

I am writing file to disk on unix with permission 0777, but the `ls -la` shows it has `-rwxr-xr-x` which is not expected.

```
 err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, jsonByte, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
```

I expect `-rwxrwxrwx` permission. I do not understand why `w` permission is missing.

Comment: If the file already exists, WriteFile will not change the perms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as [Burak Serdar notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679628/fail-to-write-file-with-permission-0777#comment107357837_60679628), be sure that this really is a *new* file, as the OS will generally leave the existing permissions in place when overwriting an existing file (though the details are OS-specific, and in particular [some Unix-ish OSes clear setuid/setgid here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284947/162084)).

Unix/Linux file permissions work by having the OS *clear* any permissions that the user requests be *removed*, from the permissions that the *program* requests be granted.

That is, when calling a file system operation that creates a new file, you, in your code, supply a mode.  In this case you are supplying `0777` which is indeed `rwxrwxrwx`.

Meanwhile, however, the *user's operating environment*<sup>1</sup> contains another octal mode called the [*umask*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).  In this case it is presumably `022`, or `----w--w-`.  These permissions are *removed* from your supplied permissions: `0777 & (^022)` is `0755` which is `rwxr-xr-x`.  So the newly created *file* has mode `rwxr-xr-x`, or `0755`, even though your program asked for `0777`.

For this reason, most Unix programs should use one of two modes during file creation operation: `0777` for directories and executable files, and `0666` for non-executable files.  The user's umask will remove unwanted permissions: users who want privacy can set their umask to `077` which will remove `rwx` for both group and other, leaving only `0700` or `0600` as appropriate.

One exception to this rule is that any *program* that wants to ensure extra privacy—such as `ssh`-related code, when it creates key-pairs—should supply its mode as `0600` so that there are no group and other-user permission bits set in the first place.

Note that `chmod` calls *do not* have the user's umask setting applied.  If you need to discover the user's umask to compute the correct value for a `chmod` call, use either the new [golang.org/sys/x/unix `Umask`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Umask) function, or the old [syscall `Umask`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Umask) function.  Unfortunately you must supply a *new* umask to discover the *original* umask.  This displaces the per-process umask until you re-install the original value.  Hence, you might want to do this in an init function and store the result in a variable for safekeeping while also restoring the original:

```
var Umask int

func init() {
    Umask = unix.Umask(0777)
    unix.Umask(Umask)
}
```

for instance (assuming the new-style; the old style `syscall.Umask` usage is identical; neither returns any error).  This makes your program Unix-specific, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>This means permissions stored in the *kernel's per-process data*, not shell-style environment variables.